# How to calculate the volatility of a compensated poisson process?

Tags: stochastic-processes

Poisson process $N(t)$ with density $\lambda$, 
could generate a compensated Poisson Process
$$M(t) = N(t) - \lambda t,$$
 $M(t)$ is a martingale with mean of $0$.

Now, how could I calculate the volatility of this compensated Poisson process $M(t)$?

ps. volatility = standard deviation, or,
let mean
$$\mu := E\{f(t)\}$$, then volatility

$$\sigma := E\{(f(t)-\mu)^2\} $$.

Comment: How to you define volatility?

Comment: volatility = standard deviation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know that the mean of the process is $0$, that's the point of being compensated. Hence, variation is just a second moment: 
$$
V(t) = \mathsf E[(N_t- \lambda t)^2]  =\mathsf E[N_t^2] - 2\lambda t \mathsf E[N_t]+\lambda^2t^2 = (\lambda t + \lambda^2t^2)-2\lambda^2t^2+\lambda^2t^2 = \lambda t
$$
so that $\sigma(t) = \sqrt{\lambda t}$.